# Unresolved external symbol calling funtion same .cpp

Tags: unresolved-external

I am trying to make a program to find saddle points in a matrix. When i try to run it compiler shows errors:   [Linker error] undefined reference to `min_cols(float (*) [6], float, int, int, int)' ,  [Linker error] undefined reference to`max_rows(float (*) [6], float, int, int, int)' 
That is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define M 8
#define N 6


void main (){
    void enter_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c);
    void print_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c);
    void min_cols (float p[M][N],float ,int , int r, int c);
    void max_rows (float p[M][N],float mr,int mri, int r, int c);
    int saddle_points (float max_row[N],int mrow_i[N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r,int c);
    int m, n,mrow_i[M],mcol_i[N],flag;
    int *mri,*mci;
    float matrix[M][N],max_row[M],min_col[N];
    float (*p) [M][N],*mr,*mc;
    p=&matrix;mr=max_row;mc=min_col;
    mri=mrow_i;mci=mcol_i;
    do{
        printf("Please enter matrix size(max 8 by 6):'\n ");
        printf("Enter number of rows M=");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        printf("Enter number of columns N=");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while((m>M||m<=0)||(n>N||n<=0));


    enter_matrix(*p,m,n);
    print_matrix(*p,m,n);
    min_cols(*p,min_col[N],mcol_i[N],m,n);
    max_rows(*p,max_row[M],mrow_i[M],m,n);
    printf("Saddle points:\n");
    flag=saddle_points (max_row,mrow_i,min_col,mcol_i,m,n);
    if(flag==0){
        printf("There are no saddle points");
    }   

}
void enter_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c){
    int i,j;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("Enter %d %d element of matrix: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%f",&p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void print_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("%f \t",p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void min_cols (float p[M][N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r, int c){
    int i,j,*mci;float min,*mc;
    mc=min_col;mci=mcol_i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    min=p[i][0];
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        if(p[i][j]<min){
            *(mc+i)=p[i][j];
            *(mci+i)=j;
        }
    }
}
}

void max_rows (float p[M][N],float max_row[M],int mrow_i[M], int r, int c){
    int i,j,*mri;float max,*mr;
    mr=max_row;mri=mrow_i;
for(j=0;j<c;j++){
    max=0;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        if(p[i][j]>max){
            *(mr+j)=p[i][j];
            *(mri+j)=j;
        }
    }
}
}

int saddle_points (float max_row[N],int mrow_i[N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r,int c){
int i,j,flag=0,*mri,*mci; float *mr,*mc;
mr=max_row;mri=mrow_i;mc=min_col;mci=mcol_i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        if(*(mr+i)==*(mc+j)){
            printf("Saddle point at row %d, col %d value:%f'n",*(mri+i),*(mci+i),*(mr+i));
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

Comment: If this is C, you'll have to declare your functions *before* `main()`, so the linker knows about them. Not *inside* `main()`, like you do now.

Comment: Are you writing C code in a file with a .cpp extension? That is very confusion, and may/will cause errors for the compiler.

Comment: Tryed to declare before main function, still the same error

Comment: Could you update your question with the amended code. Is the error *exactly* the same?

Comment: It is exactly the same

Comment: Your function declaration and your function definitions are not the same. Look more closely at the arguments, especially the second and third argument of `min_cols`: array of float/int versus float/int.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution i should have put the prototypes of functions before main this is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 8
#define N 6

void enter_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c);
void print_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c);
void min_cols (float p[M][N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r, int c){
    int i,j,*mci;float min,*mc;
    mc=min_col;mci=mcol_i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    min=p[i][0];
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        if(p[i][j]<min){
            *(mc+i)=p[i][j];
            *(mci+i)=j;
        }
    }
}
}

void max_rows (float p[M][N],float max_row[M],int mrow_i[M], int r, int c){
    int i,j,*mri;float max,*mr;
    mr=max_row;mri=mrow_i;
for(j=0;j<c;j++){
    max=0;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        if(p[i][j]>max){
            *(mr+j)=p[i][j];
            *(mri+j)=j;
        }
    }
}
}
int saddle_points (float max_row[N],int mrow_i[N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r,int c);
void main (){

    int m, n,mrow_i[M],mcol_i[N],flag;
    int *mri,*mci;
    float matrix[M][N],max_row[M],min_col[N];
    float (*p) [M][N],*mr,*mc;
    p=&matrix;mr=max_row;mc=min_col;
    mri=mrow_i;mci=mcol_i;
    do{
        printf("Please enter matrix size(max 8 by 6):'\n ");
        printf("Enter number of rows M=");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        printf("Enter number of columns N=");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while((m>M||m<=0)||(n>N||n<=0));


    enter_matrix(*p,m,n);
    print_matrix(*p,m,n);
    min_cols(*p,min_col,mcol_i,m,n);
    max_rows(*p,max_row,mrow_i,m,n);
    printf("Saddle points:\n");
    flag=saddle_points (max_row,mrow_i,min_col,mcol_i,m,n);
    if(flag==0){
        printf("There are no saddle points");
    }   

}
void enter_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c){
    int i,j;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("Enter %d %d element of matrix: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%f",&p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void print_matrix (float p[M][N], int r, int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("%f \t",p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



int saddle_points (float max_row[N],int mrow_i[N],float min_col[N],int mcol_i[N],int r,int c){
int i,j,flag=0,*mri,*mci; float *mr,*mc;
mr=max_row;mri=mrow_i;mc=min_col;mci=mcol_i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        if(*(mr+i)==*(mc+j)){
            printf("Saddle point at row %d, col %d value:%f'n",*(mri+i),*(mci+i),*(mr+i));
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't answer your question; *edit* your question with the amended code (since the error is the same).

Comment: OK noted that .